# JSON array of objects with properties “from” and “to” and group it by time period

Tags: javascript, json

In case if dates in the array are intersect then function should  combine them in one period, else periods should be separated

```js
var dates = [
{
"from":"03/01/2021",
"to":"03/05/2021"
  },
  {
"from":"03/08/2021",
"to":"03/10/2021"
  },
  {
"from":"03/07/2021",
"to":"03/20/2021"
  }

   ];
var item = dates;
var index = 0;
var out = document.querySelector('#test');
for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
    index++;
    var from_i = Date.parse(item[i].from);
    var to_i = Date.parse(item[i].to);
    var from_index = Date.parse(item[index].from);
    var to_index = Date.parse(item[index].to);
    if(from_index >= from_i && from_index <= to_i){
        let updated_from = new Date(from_index);
        let update_to = new Date(to_index);
        console.log(updated_from);
        out.innerHTML += updated_from.toDateString() + update_to.toDateString() + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"> </div>
```

Case of incoming jSON:
[
{
"from":"03/01/2021",
"to":"03/06/2021"
},
{
"from":"03/10/2021",
"to":"03/15/2021"
},
{
"from":"03/20/2021",
"to":"03/25/2021"
}
]

Output:  Mar 1-5, 7-20

Can some help? Learning JS…little bit hard for me(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Georgy! What have you tried so far? Please update the question with code example of your own.

Comment: Yes, added on top

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const data = [ { "from":"03/01/2021", "to":"03/06/2021" }, { "from":"03/10/2021", "to":"03/15/2021" }, { "from":"03/20/2021", "to":"03/25/2021" } ]

const monthToString = month => {
  const months = {
    '01': 'Jan',
    '02': 'Feb',
    '03': 'Mar',
    '04': 'Apr',
    '05': 'May',
    '06': 'Jun',
    '07': 'Jul',
    '08': 'Aug',
    '09': 'Sep',
    '10': 'Oct',
    '11': 'Nov',
    '12': 'Dec',
    
  }
  return months[month] || month
}


const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((res, {from, to}) => {
  const [monthFrom, day, year] = from.split('/')
  const [m, dayTo, y] = to.split('/')
  
  const month = monthToString(m)
  
  return {
   ...res,
   [month]: [...(res[month] || []), [day, dayTo]]
  }
  
}, {})).map(([month, days]) => `${month} ${days.map(([from, to]) => `${parseInt(from)}-${parseInt(to)}`).join(', ')}`).join('\n')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: almost.. but if date[1].from is on between '03/01/2021' and '03/06/2021' need to display Mar 1-15